# Make UIButton act as navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

How can I make a regular UIButton act as a navigationcontroller so that when it's pressed I can open up a new view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create yourButton in viewDidLoad method as following way...

```
UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[yourButton setTitle:@"YearButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(240, 40, 75, 30);     
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[self.view addSubview:yourButton];
```

This is your method code and createViewController which is object of CreateViewController class and it is declared in .h file.....

```
-(void) buttonSelected:(id)sender{
   if (!createViewController) {
                createViewController = [[CreateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateViewController" bundle:nil];

            }


            [self.navigationController pushViewController:createViewController animated:YES];

 }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Why are you creating a UIBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a UINavigation controller in your project.

then for the buttons action just call

```
[yourUIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and for the method that gets called just do the following:

```
-(void)buttonAction{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:YourViewController animated:YES];
}
```