# How to Navigate UIViewController as target of UIButton action created in programmatically

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

i am creating UIButton Programatically.I want a UIViewController to be the target of that button action.How would I do that?.If i click the button navigation will not work.This is my code.please help me anybody.Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    weeklyAudio=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [weeklyAudio addTarget:self action:@selector(weeklyPredictions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [weeklyAudio setTitle:@"WEEKLY PREDICTIONS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    weeklyAudio.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;            
    weeklyAudio.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    [weeklyAudio.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [weeklyAudio setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 10, 10, 10)];
    [weeklyAudio.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
    weeklyAudio.frame=CGRectMake(10, 20, 140, 120);
    weeklyAudio.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    weeklyAudio.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:232.0f/255.0f green:52.0f/255.0f blue:27.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

    [backGroundImage addSubview:weeklyAudio];

    weeklyAudioImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 10, 48, 48)];
    weeklyAudioImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"m48*48.png"];
    [weeklyAudio addSubview:weeklyAudioImage];
    weeklyAudio.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
}

-(void)weeklyPredictions
{
    WeeklyViewController *weekly=[[WeeklyViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:weekly animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213703/make-uibutton-act-as-navigationcontroller/12213841#12213841

Comment: What does "If i click the button navigation will not work" mean? What happens when you click the button? You also say that you "want a UIViewController to be the target of that button" -- what view controller? The one this code is in, or some other controller?

Comment: If you use .xib file then you have define like this WeeklyViewController *weekly=[[WeeklyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WeeklyViewController" bundle:nil]; or if you use storyboard then like this WeeklyViewController *weekly= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WeeklyViewController"];

Comment: @Maul thanks for responsde.I am creating programatically.I am not using xib and storyboard

Comment: @rdelmar thanks for your response.i mean if i click the button the WeeklyViewController will not navigate

Comment: Is this view controller (`self`) in a navigation controller? If not then you can't push another view controller.

Comment: @maddy thanks for your response.But i cant understand to your post.please give example based on my code.

Comment: You mean it does nothing? Also, you probably want to instantiate your WeaklyViewController using something other than alloc init. If that controller's view is made in a xib file, then you should use alloc initWithNibName:bundle:. If it's made in a storyboard, then you should use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Comment: please help me any body...

Comment: @user3222991 i used your code in my demo project its works. its navigate to another viewcontroller

Comment: @user3222991 you take a global navigation controller for all other view controller? if you not take that then it not work

Comment: @Maul what method can i apply globally?please help me

Comment: @user3222991 what you use for project xibs or storyboard?

Comment: I am not using xib or storyboard.I am completely written programatically

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49524/discussion-between-maul-and-user3222991)

Comment: maybe there's no self.navigationController, just saying.

Comment: Did you add navigationController in AppDelegate?

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi thank u.But i cant found any solution.please help me

Comment: Did you try to **log** in your `weeklyPredictions` method. Take a `NSLog(@"BreakPoint");` in your `weeklyPredictions` method to check that whether its is running or not.

Comment: hey i took background image in this view like "  backGroundImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 480)];
        
        
        backGroundImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dash-bord-bg-small.PNG"];
        
        [self.view addSubview:backGroundImage];"

Comment: I said that try to use log in your button's action

Comment: Are you able to present a view controller? Like "[self presentViewController:weekly animated:YES completion:nil];"

Comment: You haven't answered the question about having a navigation controller. If you put this log, NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController) in the weeklyPredictions method, what does it give you?

Answer (score 0):

set a breakpoint in `-(void)weeklyPredictions`,  then debug to see if run in the method when you click the button. If run in it, print `po [self navigationController]` in console to see if the viewController has a navigation controller . If result is nil, then you can't push another view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a navigation controller to push and pop viewcontrollers? If not..
use

```
[self presentViewController:weekly animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to present your next viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code before `addSubview`

```
[weeklyAudio addTarget:self action:@selector(weeklyPredictions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And edit your `weeklyPredictions` method as:

```
-(void)weeklyPredictions {
    WeeklyViewController *weekly=[[WeeklyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([WeeklyViewController class]) bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:weekly animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: The OP already has the line to add a target to the button. And changing how the `WeeklyViewController` is initialized might be appropriate, it has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line in your viewDidLoad menthol:

```
backGroundImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Since by default user interaction is disabled for UIImageView so any subview added to image view will not get touch events.

Hope it will solve your problem, if yes please vote it.

Regards,
Satendra

Comment: What? He's using a button. This has nothing to do with the problem.